# javascript and this

Tags: javascript

```
function distance(r,t){
        this.rate = r,
        this.time = t,
        this.calculate = function() {return rate * time ;};
        return this;
}

var trip1 = distance(2,4);
var trip2 = distance(5,7);
var trip3 = distance(3,10);
document.write("<br>trip1: " + trip1.calculate());
document.write("<br>trip2: " + trip2.calculate());
document.write("<br>trip3: " + trip3.calculate());
```

**ouput**

```
trip1: 30
trip2: 30
trip3: 30
```

Shouldn't the output be

```
trip1: 8
trip2: 35
trip3: 30
```

Answer (score 5):

Each new distance should be a NEW object. Also, inside calculate, you have to refer to the current instance by the "this" keywork

```
function distance(r,t){
        this.rate = r,
        this.time = t,
        this.calculate = function() {return this.rate * this.time ;};
        return this;
}

var trip1 = new distance(2,4);
var trip2 = new distance(5,7);
var trip3 = new distance(3,10);
document.write("<br>trip1: " + trip1.calculate());
document.write("<br>trip2: " + trip2.calculate());
document.write("<br>trip3: " + trip3.calculate());
```

**EDIT The example above without NEW keyword:**

```
function distance(r,t){
        if ( !(this instanceof distance) ) //checking if I'm using 'new' or not
            return new distance(r, t); 
        this.rate = r,
        this.time = t,
        this.calculate = function() {return this.rate * this.time ;};
        return this;
}

var trip1 = distance(2,4);
var trip2 = distance(5,7);
var trip3 = distance(3,10);
document.write("<br>trip1: " + trip1.calculate());
document.write("<br>trip2: " + trip2.calculate());
document.write("<br>trip3: " + trip3.calculate());
```

Comment: Douglas Crockford would advise against using the `new` operator in any case. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your function `distance()` you're setting the `rate` and `time` property on the global `window` object, because you're not instantiating trip objects using the `new` operator. `return this` inside the function returns the `window` object, so essentially, you're overwriting the properties three times.

The correct solution is given by [@steweb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689396/javascript-and-this/4689416#4689416).

EDIT: Adding example without `new` keyword:

```
var createTripObject = function(rate, time) {
  var r = rate, t = time;
  return {
    calculate: function() { return r * t; }
  };
};

var trip1 = createTripObject(2, 4);
var trip2 = createTripObject(5, 7);
document.write('<br/>trip1: ' + trip1.calculate());
document.write('<br/>trip2: ' + trip2.calculate());
```

The method return a new object that can acccess local variables inside the object scope but are unavailable from outside the scope, essentially creating pseudo-private members.

Comment: how to do the above without new the new keyword?

Comment: @Apotheosis @Krof Drakula : I edited my example and I added a solution that avoid (by using instanceof trick) the use of the "new" keyword for each distance instance I want to create ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `this` object is the 'owner' of the current context. In your `distance` function the owner will be the global object, in other words the `window` object. Hence, when you call `distance()` multiple times, each invocation will overwrite the previous values of `r`, `t` and `calculate` in the `window` object.

To create each trip variable as a separate object, use the `new` keyword e.g.

```
var trip1 = new distance(2,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the OP on Krof Drakula's answer:

> "how to do the above without new the new keyword?"

Just access the parameters then. It will work.

```
function distance(rate, time) {
    return {
        calculate: function() { return rate * time; }
    };
}
```

If you need access to `rate` and `time` property, both get and set, you can define it as a part of the object.

```
function distance(rate, time) {
    return {
        rate: rate,
        time: time,
        calculate: function() { return this.rate * this.time; }
    };
}
```